# Remove tables.less Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I have the following line in my tables.less, that I do not want in my code.

```
th {
text-align: left;
}
```

Problem is, that I do not have tables.less in my website directory, so I can't remove the line - and I cannot override the text-align, as I don't want any text-align at all.

How can I edit or remove elements from the Bootstrap 3 tables.less?

Comment: Please mark the answer as the solution unless you have anything more to add

Answer (score 1):

To remove this you can go to http://getbootstrap.com/2.0.4/less.html and learn how to generate CSS from the Bootstrap LESS code and how to use that in your code. You can modify some things on the webpage, but I think you'll need to get the LESS files, remove this snippet you don't want and compile the CSS.

Otherwise you can download and edit the bootstrap CSS where you remove this code. Then you'll need to use your version of the bootstrap CSS

Or the simplest thing would probably be to create your own CSS rule to override the Boostrap rule and place it in your own CSS file or script

Comment: I will look at the Bootstrap LESS code, thank you.

I will not create my own CSS rule to override, as I do not want any text-align at all. I want it completely removed.

Comment: th{text-align: initial;} might reset the rule to browser default